# Xamarin studio 5.9.7 the type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I tried to find a solution to use Xamarin.Forms but the solution in other  question don't work for Xamarin studio 5.9.6 (same as for version 5.9.7 build 22 after an update)

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App ()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new ContentPage {
                Content = new StackLayout {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }   

    }
}
```

The only available References when I tried to add that is Xamarin.Andoid.NUnitLite

I get the error cs0103

I just found how to add the package to the project , right click package in project solution and try add Xamarin.Forms but i have another error

[image]

And now the error is:

Adding Xamarin.Forms...
Adding 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323' to test.
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+dnxcore50+win+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I tried to install the 4.6 Assembly with this link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727

because it seems Xamarin.Forms needs the 4.6 one, some one can confirm that ?

but i don't know how to add that correctly to the directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework

If of course it is the solution, and try to repair the xamarian install to include that

Under OSX here is the working pcl profile78:
[image]

Because of this same error:

***Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.5.0.6447'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-net45+sl50+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.***

Can some one tell witch Assembly contained in Xamarin.Forms 1.5.0.6447 ?

Comment: some solutions explained here but they are not working for me, the profile Profile78 give the same error: link-> http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48563/could-not-install-package-xamarin-forms-1-3-3-6323

Comment: Why aren't you just creating a new XF project from the File --> New Project menu option?

Comment: i did that, I created the project with File new solution Blank Xamarin.Forms App, and I tried to add the Forms package to the app but it's not working for the reason I mentioned

Comment: I installed xamarin under OSX and there is no problem with Xamarin Forms project

Comment: this link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52664/new-pcl-project-trying-to-add-reference-to-xamarin-forms-could-not-install-package-error  recommand to use the Profile 78 or Profile 259 but it's not working too, can some one give an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the ASP.NET Core 5.0 reference or deleting the ASP.NET Core 5.0.xml file from the Profile78\SupportedFrameworks directory.

I had a similar error when making a new project.

Check this thread.  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34520